# Why when i run my JDA application, i got a "permission_overwrites" error?

Tags: java, discord

I create a bot Discord for my server with JDA API, but, when i run the programme, i got a lot of this error :

```
Received a channel for a guild that isn't a text or voice channel. JSON: {"permission_overwrites": /*other*/}
```

And a stack trace :

```
Encountered an exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Got permission_override for unknown channel with id: 361465678508851200
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.EntityBuilder.createGuildChannelPass(EntityBuilder.java:394)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.EntityBuilder.createGuildFirstPass(EntityBuilder.java:281)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.handle.GuildCreateHandler.handleInternally(GuildCreateHandler.java:39)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:38)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:770)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onTextMessage(WebSocketClient.java:500)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:803)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:368)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:270)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:990)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:749)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

I run my application like this :

```
JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
builder.setToken("Token");
builder.setAutoReconnect(true);
builder.setStatus(OnlineStatus.DO_NOT_DISTURB);
jda = builder.buildBlocking(); //With try and catch block
```

the bot still works normally, but it's strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed a tutorial and I got the same result, that the channel categories were breaking JDA.

I had to look on the JDA [Github](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA) and change my pom to match the newest version.

Change the version of JDA to 3.3.1_313. This is the latest version at the time of this writing. That should fix it, as channel categories are fairly recent. If you aren't using maven, just redownload the jar